# Error with call site when instantiating Swift class

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting an error of Extra Argument 'frameCaptureDate' In Call when I instantiate a new object from a Swift class.
Code attached.
Happens in Playground & App.

```
class SwiftFrame <NSCoding> {

    var frameFilePath: NSURL
    var frameCaptureDate: NSDate

    init(frameFilePath: NSURL, frameCaptureDate: NSDate) {
        self.frameFilePath = frameFilePath
        self.frameCaptureDate = frameCaptureDate
    }

    init(coder: NSCoder) {
        self.frameCaptureDate = coder.decodeObjectForKey("GIFFrameCaptureDate") as NSDate
        self.frameFilePath = coder.decodeObjectForKey("GIFFrameFilePath") as NSURL
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.frameCaptureDate, forKey: "GIFFrameCaptureDate")
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.frameFilePath, forKey: "GIFFrameFilePath")
    }

}

var date = NSDate.date()
var urlstring = NSURL(string: "http://apple.com")
var sf = SwiftFrame(frameFilePath: urlstring, frameCaptureDate: date) //Error here: "Extra Argument 'frameCaptureDate' In Call"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the error is a side effect of a syntax error in your class declaration. In Swift, this is how you specify protocol conformance.

```
class SwiftFrame: NSCoding {
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: Yes! You're right, it detects whether you mean superclass or protocol I remember now... many thanks! Will flag as answer soon as SO let's me...